# Dynamic Context free grammar NLTK

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

Trying to generate sentences with NLTK CFG. Would like to know if it is possible to connect sql database to feed noun and verb in the program below.
In the example below door, window, open, close are hardcoded. How to dynamically ask nltk to look from say excel or database column to feed noun and verb in this particular context?

```
import nltk   
from nltk.parse.generate import generate,demo_grammar   
from nltk import CFG   
grammar = CFG.fromstring("""   
S -> VP NP   
NP -> Det N   
VP -> V   
Det ->'the '   
N -> 'door' | 'window'   
V -> 'Open' | 'Close'    
""")    
print(grammar)   
for sentence in generate(grammar, n=100):   
   print(' '.join(sentence))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can't dynamically change an NLTK CFG – once it is instantiated, it stays put. You need to define all of the vocabulary immediately when constructing the CFG.

As far as I can see, you have two options to include comprehensive vocabulary from an external resource:

1. Build up a grammar string as in the example you posted, and use `CFG.fromstring()` to parse it. You might have to take care of some escaping issues (eg. quotes/apostrophes in the terminal symbols).
2. Use the CFG constructor directly, providing it a list of *productions*, eg.:

   ```
   from nltk import CFG, Production, Nonterminal
   prods = [Production(Nonterminal('S'), (Nonterminal('PN'), Nonterminal('V'))),
            Production(Nonterminal('PN'), ('Sam',)),
            Production(Nonterminal('PN'), ('Fred',)),
            Production(Nonterminal('V'), ('sleeps',))]
   g = CFG(Nonterminal('S'), prods)
   ```

   This looks somewhat verbose, but it's probably easier and faster to construct this nested structure of Python datatypes rather than writing a bug-free serialiser for the (more concise) grammar string format.

Comment: Thanks lenZ learned about Standford parser, is it possible to generate CFG from stanford parser? For example say sentence "Open the gate" is parsed as "(ROOT
  (S
    (VP (VB Open)
      (NP (DT the) (NN gate)))))" is there a easy way apart from manually coding it to cfg.formstring for this parsed format.

Comment: I don't know much about the Stan(d)ford parser. It might be possible to export its contained grammar, but if it's a statistical parser, this won't be fun. What are you trying to do? Training a new parser from the output of an existing parser can be sensible in certain cases, but a CFG is most probably not suitable for this.

Comment: My intention is to parse a sentence using a parser and study the parse tree. To replicate the parse tree in ntlk as the example showed in my  first post and seed it with objects to auto generate sentences.